# Flask SQLalchemy, password is not stored in database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store users in a database when they register to my flask website using SQL alchemy, the username and income stores correctly but the hashed password does not appear in the database and I don't know why. My register function is here:

```
def register():
    # connect database to flask

    # name = username
    username = request.form.get("username")
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ensure username is entered
        if not username:
            flash("must enter username")
            return render_template("register.html")
        # ensure password is entered
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            flash("must enter password")
            return render_template("register.html")

        # ensure password has been confirmed
        elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
            flash("must confirm password")
            return render_template("register.html")
        # ensure income has been entered
        elif not request.form.get("income"):
            flash("must enter Monthly income to proceed")
            return render_template("register.html")

        # ensure password and confirmation password match
        elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
            flash("passwords do not match")
            return render_template("register.html")

        # query database to see if username is already taken
        founduser = users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        # hash password
        _hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
        income = request.form.get("income")
        if founduser:
            flash("username is already taken")
            return render_template("register.html")
        else:
            registereduser = users(username, _hash, income)
            db.session.add(registereduser)
            db.session.commit()
            _id = registereduser._id
        session["user_id"] = _id
        flash("registered successfully!")
        return redirect("/home")

    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

the user table is here:

```
class users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column("username", db.String(100))
    _hash = db.Column("hash", db.String(100))
    income = db.Column("income", db.Float)

    def __init__(self, username, _hash, income):
        self.username = username
        self._hash = _hash
        self.income = income
        return f"<User: {self.username}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test, but i believe it is just a typo issue:

```
self.hash = _hash
```

According to your model , it should be `self._hash = _hash`

Comment: Fixed this, but now I'm getting an error saying: 
registereduser = users(username, _hash, income)
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'str'
any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Jay Class constructors should never `return`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, managed to solve it by taking the return out of __init__() and creating a differernt function for returning users